# Running JavaScript code from bookmarklet when site is visited

Tags: javascript, embedded, bookmarklet

I'm wondering if there is a way to run a bookmarklet's code on the user's machine whenever someone visits my website.

I don't want the user to have the code, so they can't setup their own bookmarklet for this, and they are only able to go to this site to run the code.

How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: That is something the user would have to set up

Comment: A bookmarklet that the user doesn't have the code for directly is just JavaScript embedded in a webpage again. So just give them a link?

Comment: Just add a link with the `href` `javascript:[[Your code here]]` where `[[Your code here]]` is the JavaScript you want to run. It's not what you said but it will function the same. `<a href="javascript:example()">Example</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarklets are stored in the user's browser, so it can be inspected / edited by the user.

If you own the website, then you can add a script to the page as a tag at the end of the body tag.

This would run on page load.

Below is the structure of a website with the script. This is sub-optimal solution but without more context I think it is the best answer.

Consider looking into Javascript and page load events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Styles, Assets and Metadata -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HTML content -->
    <script>
      // JavaScript that will run on page load
      // Put your bookmarklet code here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```